# How to create a custom domain link using branch doesn't send any valuable information in Android

Tags: android, branch, branch.io, deeplink

Using branch.io I'm able to target specific URL in my app.
Since I use custom domain name I can't do it anymore on Android.
When I use a link like

> myapp.com/#/param
>   , myapp.com being registered on https://dashboard.branch.io/link-settings , I get my url in the "non_branch_link" attribute of the branch data in iOS and on browser, but not on Android where it is something like "myapp://open?link_click_id=123456789XXX".

Do you know how I can recover the initial URL or if it's a bug ?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are opening the Android app via URI scheme (e.g. Chrome), that is the expected result. If you want the "non_branch_link" attribute to contain the initial URL, you must implement App Links (Android equivalent of Universal Links) to open the app directly:

```
I/BranchSDK: posting to https://api.branch.io/v1/install
I/BranchSDK: Post value = {"hardware_id":"39caf5fa-39ae-45c8-88b9-de1c061c6dab","is_hardware_id_real":false,"brand":"LGE","model":"Nexus 5X","screen_dpi":420,"screen_height":1794,"screen_width":1080,"wifi":false,"ui_mode":"UI_MODE_TYPE_NORMAL","os":"Android","os_version":26,"country":"US","language":"en","app_version":"1.0","facebook_app_link_checked":false,"is_referrable":1,"debug":true,"update":2,"latest_install_time":1510601387046,"latest_update_time":1527289172137,"first_install_time":1510601387046,"previous_update_time":0,"environment":"FULL_APP","uri_scheme":"directory","android_app_link_url":"https:\/\/directory.app.link\/ThHCzVJvdN","external_intent_uri":"https:\/\/directory.app.link\/ThHCzVJvdN","cd":{"mv":"-1","pn":"com.brian.directory"},"metadata":{},"instrumentation":{"v1\/install-qwt":"0","v1\/install-brtt":"32"},"sdk":"android2.18.1","branch_key":"key_test_okzKiOjpEQ59noo95HfDxfgbDsfdcPCW"}
I/BranchSDK: returned {"session_id":"528681555951304587","identity_id":"528681555917749106","link":"https://directory.test-app.link?%24identity_id=528681555917749106","data":"{\"+non_branch_link\":\"https://directory.app.link/ThHCzVJvdN\",\"+clicked_branch_link\":false,\"+is_first_session\":true}","device_fingerprint_id":"528681555808722227"}
I/Choreographer: Skipped 157 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/BRANCH SDK: {"+non_branch_link":"https:\/\/directory.app.link\/ThHCzVJvdN","+clicked_branch_link":false,"+is_first_session":true}
```

Comment: Thank for the answer but I'm not sure that I understand.
I already configured app link on https://dashboard.branch.io/link-settings. If I use the Android URI Scheme it's working like expected.
If I use the http Scheme defined in the "link domain" of the ttps://dashboard.branch.io/link-settings page, it seems that Branch detects that the app exists on the device, like explained on the Android section of the configuration, and open the app with the Android URI Sheme defined in the configuration. But with the "link_click_id" instead of my custom path.
How to get the params ?